# D3 pie - Setting a max value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently using D3 pie to create a horse shoe component to display how many remaining holidays I currently have left.

Currently the data is as basic as this:

```
Data = [5,25];
```

The data is set up to represent something along these lines:

```
Data = [remainingHolidays, totalHolidays]
```

I was wondering how I'd be able to set a `Max value` on a D3 pie chart to compare how many `remainingHolidays` I've got against `totalHolidays`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do

```
Data = [remainingHolidays, totalHolidays - remainingHolidays]
```

Whole pie will represent 'totalHolidays' and slices will be 'remainingHolidays' and 'spentHolidays'

Comment: I had something like this originally but I don't think I implemented it properly. Thanks for the solution :)